# disable null value in mysql search

Tags: php, mysql, null

My database table has many columns.
I want to do a search based on multiple columns.
Sometimes it may not be the value of some columns.
How do these fields in sql query to be ineffective?
Thank you.

for examle:

```
$C1=$_POST[c1];

$C2=$_POST[c2];

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1='$c1' AND column2='$c2'
```

i want if C2 be nulled, disable it from sql query.

One way is:

```
if(!$_POST[C2]){
   SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1='$c1'
}
```

...

I want do it through sql query to do because My table has many columns.

Comment: By definition, if you are looking for a specific value, then as NULL != anything, then it will automatically be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should never write queries with variables inside like that. Learn about [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) / [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Second, key references for an array should either be a string or integer; the expression `$_POST[c1]` will most likely cause a notice and implicit conversion to a string. It's better to write `$_POST['c1']`.

Third, and to answer your question, you can use `isset()` and `strlen()` to determine whether a value is "empty", i.e. empty string.

```
$params = array($_POST['c1']); // you should also check whether $_POST['c1'] is defined too
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE column1 = ?';
if (isset($_POST['c2']) && strlen($_POST['c2'])) {
    $sql .= ' AND column2 = ?';
    $params[] = $_POST['c2'];
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Build an array of conditions by iterating through the POST values, adding a condition if the respective POST parameter is not empty:

```
$conditions = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if (!empty($value)) {
    $conditions[] =
      $dbcolumn[$key] . " = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
  }
}
```

You will need an array `$dbcolumn` that matches POST variables to the database columns (or you have to provide some other means of translating between the two).

Now create a SQL query for the given conditions:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable';
if (!empty($conditions)) {
  $query .= ' WHERE '  . join(' AND ', $conditions);
}
```

Note that the extension that provides [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is deprectaded. You should probably use some other extension to comunicate with the MySQL server and would than have to use the repsective call of the other extension.

Answer (score 0):

This code not recomended, but if you realy want to do it on MySQL, you can use LIKE syntax like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1="$c1" AND column2="$c2%"
```

Add % character before or after $c2

Please don't do it!!

Comment: Thank you friends for all the useful content.